# Hide product or variation if has a custom field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I need to be able to hide some products and / or variations in a Woocommerce with WPML only for some languages at certain times.

I tried everything, tried to disable the synchronization of the _stock_status that manages WPML but I have not been able and it has occurred to me to add a custom field to each one (in the case of the variations I suppose I would have to do it via database because in the dashboard there is no option) and have a check:

if "custom_field" exists => _stock_status = outofstock (or simply deactivate the add to cart button and display a message.)

This is "easy" for the products, but I don't know how to solve it with the variations. Any ideas? I also hear other solutions to the problem.